# Date considers a Timestamp from the future as a date from the past

Tags: php, date, datetime

I have a loop who counts weekend days, it works like this:

```
$weekends = 0;
while ($begin <= $today) {
    $no_days++;
    $what_day = date("N", $begin);
    if ($what_day > 5) {
        $weekends++;
    };
    $begin += 86400;
};
```

$begin is the first day of the month, and $today is today and I get them like this:

```
$begin = date("Y-m-01");
$today = date("Y-m-d");
```

$begin and $today are correct, but for some reason my loop is saying that 3 consecutive days are weekend. I printed te value of $begin on inside the if for debuggin reasons and I get the following output:

> 2016-11-05 12:11:00(1478329200)
>
> 2016-11-06 12:11:00(1478415600)
>
> 2016-11-06 11:11:00(1478502000)

Instead, what I expect to get is:

> 2016-11-05 12:11:00(1478329200)
>
> 2016-11-06 12:11:00(1478415600)
>
> 2016-11-07 12:11:00(1478502000)

This script as been working good for several months, but today stop working. I have a `date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');` at the beggining.

I don't completely understand how dates works, so, I'm not really sure how to start looking for the problem, so, if this is a timezone related problem and somebody want to point me to a source of information to learn on this topic I will be really happy :)

EDIT: As @Devon points out. I changed `$end` for `$today` to avoid misunderstandings.

Comment: Funny how this happens during daylight savings time....

Comment: Thanks @JohnConde, "daylight saving time" get me to the answer ;)!. I will let the question here until I read enough to make a good answer or somebody write a good answer for this.

Comment: There are any number of headaches you can get by simply assuming that "tomorrow" is "today plus 86400 seconds".  Consider some other way to get from one day to the next.

Comment: I get the "today plus 86400" from SO :(, thanks @Kevin_Kinsey, I will consider that!

Comment: Why would `$end = date("Y-m-d");`?  Wouldn't it be `$end = date("Y-m-t");`? As `t` stands for the number of days in the month while `d` is just the current day of the month

Comment: @Devon My mistake, $end should be $today becouse -->  "...of the month, and $end is today and I get them..."

Comment: Use `DateTime` with `DateInterval`

Comment: Please people, if you're going to downvote this question, provide a comment telling what is wrong, I don't care about points, but I care about being a good user in SO. If you're going to down vote my question and wont provide a comment explaining what's wrong you're not making SO a better please, but a bitter one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider working with PHP's `DateTime`, `DateInterval`, and `DatePeriod` classes.

```
function countWeekendDaysBetweenDateTimes(DateTime $start, DateTime $end) {
    $weekend_count = 0;
    // one day interval
    $interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
    // get date period object based on start, end, interval
    $date_period = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);
    foreach($date_period as $dt) {
        if ((int)$dt->format('N') > 5) {
            $weekend_count++;
        }
    }
    return $weekend_count;
}
```

These classes will be much more reliable to work with when dealing with ranges and recurrences of dates and will generally also simplify dealing with timezones (`DateTimeZone`), daylight savings, leap years, and other anomalies of our calendar and time systems.

Comment: Thanks @mike this works as expected!, just for learning purposes. It's recommended to make a casting of the string returned by format to compare it with a string?, why?

Comment: @Icjury `5` is an integer value I am using for comparison (as you did in your example).  The way this comparison is being made truly more of an integer type comparison, so I like to cast the output of `format()` to integer for like for like comparison purposes. As a matter of course I like to compare two items as explicitly as possible - for example almost always using strict comparison (`===`, `!===`) vs. loose comparison (`==`, `!=`).   Since return value of `format('N')` is so predictable in this case, it doesn't really matter though.